# What's the point of delay signing of an .NET assembly?

Tags: c#, .net

I noticed that after I use **AssemblyDelaySignAttribute** to indicate that an assembly is in development and does not need to be signed now, I'll have to use **sn -Vr foolib.dll** to register for strong name verification to be **turned off** for this assembly.

What's the point of doing this **circle**? Why not just leave the assembly unsigned until it's fully done? Isn't that less bothering?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A couple reasons...

1. Assemblies without a strong name cannot be added to the GAC
2. Related to #1, assemblies not in the GAC do not benefit much from NGEN
3. Strong named assemblies exhibit different behavior when it comes to assembly probing and loading with partial names.
4. Assemblies without a strong name cannot be referenced by a strong named assembly

So in organizations where the signing process is tightly controlled, it helps to be able to fake it out for development.

Comment: one of the few answers that actually explain the _motivation_, not just the use case or the mechanism - thumbs up!

Comment: Sorry - I'm new to this and relate to the question but can't grok this answer.  Aren't those 4 reasons just explaining the need for strong signing?  But if - in a development environment or otherwise - you decide you're prepared to use an assembly that's not strongly signed, and I thought this was the real question: what's more secure or desirable about "delayed signing" compared to no signing at all?  Why can't we have a signing-free dev environment then suffer the pain of signing when it actually adds security?  Surely a delay signing with a public key is a joke?  Any insight appreciated...

Comment: Because unsigned assemblies can't be placed in the GAC and have very different loading behavior.

Answer (score 7):

From [AssemblyDelaySignAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblydelaysignattribute.aspx)

> Delayed signing is used when the
>   author of the assembly does not have
>   access to the private key that will be
>   used to generate the signature

Answer (score 3):

This is the scenario that Delay Signing is supposed to prevent:

Your company makes trading systems for banks.  Jack is a disgruntled employee.  He's been working on your team for a year and has had access to the private key used to sign the assemblies because it's part of the build that everyone uses.  Jack has a blowout with his manager and leaves with all the source code.  Now Jack decides to get even.  He goes fishing for employees of the bank where your software is located and he gets a few of them to download a utility that swaps out a legitimate assembly for one that Jack built and signed.  Because the signatures match, the calling program is never any wiser that a critical component has been compromised.

The purpose of 'Delay Signing' is that only the build engineers have access to the signature.  This, theoretically, reduces the number of people you need to trust implicitly with your source code.  The software engineers are expected to disable (ignore) strong-name checking when they build and debug.