# Regarding delay signing?

Tags: .net

i got question about delay signing. the definition of delay signing is : --

Delay signing allows you to place a shared assembly in the GAC by signing the assembly with just the public key. This allows the assembly to be signed with the private key at a later stage, when the development process is complete and the component or assembly is ready to be deployed. This process enables developers to work with shared assemblies as if they were strongly named, and it secures the private key of the signature from being accessed at differen

from here few things is not clear to me.
1) how to signed assembly with the private key at a later stage after signing with public key and placed in GAC.

2) why people sign any assembly with private key.

3) This process enables developers to work with shared assemblies as if they were strongly named, and it secures the private key of the signature from being accessed at differen

what does it mean? "it secures the private key of the signature from being accessed at differen"

please discuss. thanks

Comment: Part of the problem could be that you cut thr quote in mid-sentence. And because you didn't include a link we can't look for ourselves.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the point of delay signing of an .NET assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680163/whats-the-point-of-delay-signing-of-an-net-assembly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The private key should be kept in a secure place so it can never be used by a 3rd party to sign an assembly.  That's a big deal for big companies like Microsoft and others.  Having access to the private key for Silverlight would allow you to run insecure code in any browser for example.  Accordingly, that key is stored in a highly secure location, out of reach of but a few select trusted employees.

Delayed signing allows the developers to get their job done.  The assembly is signed before it leaves the building with the -R option of sn.exe

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple. Delay signing allows working with pseudo-signed libraries in large development groups.

And only a small number of persons needs access to the real (complete) key for signing the Release builds.